# using notes.forEach(function(element,index) gives error that notes is not function in for each loop.Can someone check what is problem with my code

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, function

I need to get shownotes on my webpage after I type my notes (txt1) It get saved in localstorage but I not receive it as showNotes(function used) instead code just work behind in console but there is no output at html page for showNotes. Also, using notesObj.forEach(function(element,index) gives error that notes is not function in for each loop.Can someone check what is problem with my code.

```
localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify({ txt1: [] }));
    let btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
    btn1.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
          
          let notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));
          notes.txt1.push(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
          localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes))
          console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")))
          showNotes();
        });
    
    function showNotes(){
      
      
      let notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));
      notes.txt1.push(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
      localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes));
      notesObj=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));
        let html="";
        notesObj.forEach(function(element,index){
        html += `
        div class="mycard-2 mx-2 card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Note ${index + 1}</h5>
          <p class="card-text"> ${element}</p>
          
          <button class="btn btn-primary" id ="btn2">delete note</button>
        </div>
      </div>`;
     });
     let notesElm=document.getElementById('notes');
     if(notes.length !=0){
      notesElm.innerHTML=html;
     }
    }
```

Comment: The type of notesObj is Object, there is no foreach method for an object foreach is for arrays. You can either make notesObj an array or use `for ... in` or `Objects.entries()`  :).

Comment: I have tried creating array for notes.Obj but still I am unable to show shownotes on my html web page. Is there any problem with html+= code

Comment: html += ` div , the div tag is not opened.

Comment: I am getting shonote now but notes are get added in just one card. its not repeated

Comment: Have you made the changes to the loop? can you share it here or better yet on jsfiddle or something?

Comment: function showNotes(){const entries= Object.entries(notesObj);
   html=""
   
    entries.forEach(my_function)
    function my_function(element,index){
    html+= `
    <div class="mycard-2 mx-2 card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Note ${index+1 }</h5>
      <p class="card-text"> ${element}</p>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" id ="btn2">delete note</button>
    </div>
  </div>`;
 };
 let notesElm=document.getElementById('notes');
 if(entries.length !=0)
 {notesElm.innerHTML=html;
 }
 //notesElm.innerhtml+=content
}

Comment: change `const entries= Object.entries(notesObj);` to `const entries= Object.entries(notesObj.txt1);` that should fix it.

Comment: the array you want to forEach through is inside 'txt1' , and you can use `for of` to loop through the object, commented here (https://codepen.io/akhilashokan/pen/JjLxMME).

Comment: Hi akhil can we comunicate bit more regarding same code is there any way to communicate with you. for same code I need to change the name of notes as well( here it is giving Note1, 2 but I need to change it. Can u send me your whatsap

Comment: Hello there sorry for the late reply, you can contact me at connect.akhilashokan@gmail.com